# AWS API Gateway Error Handling with Generated SDK (Swift)

Tags: swift, aws-api-gateway

I'm fairly new to `AWS` and using `API Gateway -> Lambda -> RDS`.  Also, I'm using the generated `SDK` for Swift in my `iOS` mobile application that is consuming the `API`.

The straight forward paths work fine when returning success (200).  However, I'm trying to add in more error handling for edge cases.  If an `API` request doesn't find the resource it's expected, I'm trying to return a `404 error`.  I've added this to the API Integration Response and Method Response appropriately.  I can test this and get my error model returned as expected along with the correct `HTTP Status code of 404`.

However, I'm struggling with how to handle this on the mobile application side.  How would this be handled by the generated `SDK`?  It just throws an error in the API call and I expected a way to retrieve my "Error" model object that I've defined.

[Here is normal path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO8I1.png)

[Here is failed path with 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNCyZ.png)

Generated SDK (Swift) method:

```
public func userUseridentityGet(useridentity: String) -> AWSTask<RSAPI_UserModel> {
let headerParameters = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",           
]

let queryParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

var pathParameters:[String:Any] = [:]
pathParameters["useridentity"] = useridentity

return self.invokeHTTPRequest("GET", urlString: "/user/{useridentity}", pathParameters: pathParameters, queryParameters: queryParameters, headerParameters: headerParameters, body: nil, responseClass: RSAPI_UserModel.self) as! AWSTask<RSAPI_UserModel>
}
```

At runtime, I get the following logged out when I print the error out:

> Error occurred: Error
>   Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSAPIGatewayErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={HTTPBody={
>       code = 404;
>       message = "No Result Found.";
>       "request-id" = "132b8eaa-7b24-11e7-b1fd-d342f0413b7d";
>       type = NotFound; }, HTTPHeaderFields={type = immutable dict, count = 8, entries =>  0 :
>   x-cache = {contents = "Error
>   from cloudfront"}     1 : Content-Type = {contents = "application/json"}     3 : x-amzn-requestid =
>   {contents =
>   "131a5075-7b24-11e7-87bd-9fcb4cb4e04e"}   4 : Via = {contents = "1.1
>   bd4761ff0774f9ee778140b91a0431c9.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"}    6 :
>   Date = {contents = "Mon, 07 Aug
>   2017 03:54:13 GMT"}   10 : Content-Length = 134   11 : x-amzn-trace-id =
>   {contents =
>   "sampled=0;root=1-5987e464-d3d8f7801b7ae5aa6a52fc1b"}     12 :
>   x-amz-cf-id = {contents =
>   "QKpl64W1qDaeo0zlsx2iOwTW0oO_jyPRmMT7ByPKLnen04qiPEeD6w=="} } }

The question is how do I get that de-serialized into my "Error" object model that I've defined?  How do I appropriately detect this error condition so I can write logic in my mobile application to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a workaround, I've just handled this by manually extracting out the data.  If anyone has a better way of dealing with this.  I'd definitely be interested.

```
if let error = task?.error as NSError? {
    print("Error occurred: \(error)")
    if error.code == 1 {
        let httpBody : NSDictionary = (error.userInfo["HTTPBody"] as? NSDictionary)!
        print("Code \(httpBody["code"] ?? "none") - Type \(httpBody["type"] ?? "none") - Message \(httpBody["message"] ?? "none") - RequestID \(httpBody["request-id"] ?? "none")")
    }
    return nil
}
```